# Global Angular-formly validations

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-formly

I am using angular formly-forms in a bunch of different HTML pages on my App. I am using validation as an example:

```
                    {
                       className: 'col-xs-5',
                        key: 'poc',
                        type: 'input',
                        templateOptions: {
                            type: 'text',
                            required: true,
                            label: 'Point of Contact',
                            maxlength: 15,
                            placeholder: "Enter Point of Contact's username"
                        },
                        validators:{
                            username:{
                              expression: function(viewValue, modelValue) {
                                var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                                return !value || /^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*$/.test(value);
                              },
                              message: '$viewValue + " is not a valid username"'
                            },
                        },
```

[image: Example of Output]
I want to have this validation available on my other HTML forms as well without having to repeat the validator function. I have read that I could make a custom username type that perhaps has this validator logic & message build in? I am just again not sure how to make this global.

In my app.config.js I do have a couple global messages what work to display the error messages for the base angular-formly errors but not sure how to make it do that for my custom ones

```
  formlyValidationMessages.addStringMessage('required', 'This field is required');
  formlyValidationMessages.addStringMessage('maxlength', 'Input is too long!');
```

I cannot find a good example of someone succesfully doing this and would greatly appricate some help!

Comment: Make a directive for validation

Comment: Im pretty new to all this. Not to sure how to do that.

Comment: http://docs.angular-formly.com/v5.2.1/docs/formlyvalidationmessages   this documentation might help you about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking for how to do this in the future. Take a look at the example in this video.
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-formly-default-options

In terms of how to do it for the example I outlined.

```
> angular.module('cim').run(function(formlyConfig,
> formlyValidationMessages) {   formlyConfig.setType({
>     name: 'username',
>     defaultOptions: {
>       templateOptions: {
>           type: 'text',
>           required: true,
>           label: 'Point of Contact',
>           maxlength: 15,
>           placeholder: "Enter Point of Contact's username",
>       },
>       validators:{
>           username:{
>             expression: function(viewValue, modelValue) {
>               var value = modelValue || viewValue;
>               return !value || /^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*$/.test(value);
>             },
>             message: '$viewValue + " is not a valid username"'
>           },
>       },
>     }
```